# Keypress Event on array of Textboxes using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Array of textbox generated using following code:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    $count=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    { ?>
<input type="number"  name="marks[]" value="" id="marks'+count+'" min="0">
    <?php
    $count++;
    }
}

**JQUERY CODE**

$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#marks'+count+'").keypress(function(){
       alert("Key is pressed");
   });
    });
```

My question is how to use keypress event on every textbox using jquery?

Comment: Use the signature that binds the handler to a common parent node, and uses the `selector` argument - https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to the inputs so you can select them all

**Here you go:**

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    $count=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    { ?>
<input type="number" class="textbox"  name="marks[]" value="" id="marks'+count+'" min="0">
    <?php
    $count++;
    }
}

**JQUERY CODE**

$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(".textbox").keypress(function(e){
    alert("Key is pressed");
    console.log(e.target); //this allows to see which input was pressed
});
    });
```